# Can a class be a View in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I can define something like

```
struct SimpleView: View { ...
```

but something like

```
final class SimpleView: View { ...
```

does crash with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION during runtime. Is is impossible in general or just in my case?

Comment: Well, swift allows such construction but SwiftUI design does not. I don't remember if I met anything strict in documentation, but seems this sounded in one of WWDC sessions. Although not sure. Better don't do this, if it would be allowed Apple would show it in some of their tutorials, but everywhere there are only struct views.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: **no**.

---

The longer answer is that Swift (the language) allows it, as there is no way to prohibit a protocol from being adopted by classes (although you can force a protocol to be adopted by only classes, that's the opposite of what would be needed). However, SwiftUI relies on views being `structs` for its internal methods of updating views, so no. This is related to why you need to use `@State` for value types (because it observes when the value changes, and if a reference type was used, the view would only be updated when the object is reassigned, not when any properties change) and use `@ObservedObject` for reference types (and `ObservableObject`s need to be `class`es.

Comment: You can make View `enum`. Documentation states: `You create custom views by declaring types that conform to the View protocol.`. So any type conforming to `View` protocol should be sufficient.

Comment: @ManWithBear Huh, that's true. I was oversimplifying that they need to be value types, and I just never thought that someone would use an `enum`, but I guess it'd work. You learn something every day!

Comment: why do you think it needs to be value type? Reference to documentation/wwdc appreciated

Comment: I don't actually have a reference on this, but I've seen a bunch about that being integral to how the framework works.